# ECS metric does not match EC2's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, monitoring

I am currently using AWS ECS to run a dockerized app on EC2 (t3.small instance). When I look at my cluster metrics in the console, it doesn't match at all what I can see on the EC2 instance metrics dashboard.


Here is the CPU utilization from ECS dashboard :

[image: ECS metrics] And from EC2 :

[image: EC2 metrics]


What can explain such a difference ? Could it be because of the ECS agent ?